# how to reference function parameter in query?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

In the declared function definition I want to use value of function parameter  `item_account_id` in the select query's WHERE clause .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION UPDATE_CURRENT_BALANCE( item_account_id IN item_account.item_account_id%TYPE)                               
RETURN boolean 
AS 
BEGIN        
    if item_data_table_id = 10 then
       select current_balance_curr_id 
       from BANK_ACCOUNT 
       where item_account_id = item_account_id;        
    end if;
  RETURN true;
END UPDATE_CURRENT_BALANCE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a scoping issue because the parameter name is the same as the column.  The way Oracle's name resolution works, both these `item_account_id = item_account_id` will identify the table column. Even it we added a table alias and used it in the one side of the equality operation Oracle will still evaluate it as `1 = 1`.

The solution is simple: rename the parameter.  Using a prefix is popular:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPDATE_CURRENT_BALANCE
    ( p_item_account_id IN item_account.item_account_id%TYPE)   
RETURN boolean 
AS 
BEGIN        
    if item_data_table_id = 10 then -- the posted code has no source for this? perhaps it's another parameter?
       select current_balance_curr_id 
       from BANK_ACCOUNT 
       where item_account_id = p_item_account_id;        
    end if;
  RETURN true;
END UPDATE_CURRENT_BALANCE;
```

I presume `item_data_table_id` is another parameter which got lost in transcription.  You should prefix that too: consistency is a good thing in naming conventions.

Comment: If the function execution gets inside the IF-THEN logical block and there is no match for the input parameter, the function will error out from a `NO DATA FOUND` error. You should also tighten up the function's response to more variations of input values and their conditions.